# Flutter touchable library

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day to all. I wanted to use the touchable tool, which allows you to read clicks on the canvas, but there was an error with gesture_detector, which I don't understand how to fix. Here is the code I wrote:

```
Container(
      child: FittedBox(
          child: tooth.length == 20 && mouth != null
              ? SizedBox(
                  width: mouth?.width.toDouble(),
                  height: mouth?.height.toDouble(),
                  child: CanvasTouchDetector(
                    builder: (context) => CustomPaint(
                      painter:
                          FaceOutlinePainter(context),
                    ),
                  ))
              : Text('data')),
    ),
```

And Flutter sends me to this error. As I understand it, it does not depend on CustomPaint.

```
throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
                ErrorSummary('Incorrect GestureDetector arguments.'),
                ErrorDescription(
                  'Having both a pan gesture recognizer and a scale gesture recognizer is redundant; scale is a superset of pan.',
                ),
                ErrorHint('Just use the scale gesture recognizer.'),
              ]);
```

I will be very grateful for your help.

With best wishes,
from Dmitry

Comment: Seems like you are using both pan & scale gestures in FaceOutlinePainter class which came from `TouchyCanvas` class

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using one `Listener` per `CustomPainter`, you should use just one `Listener` for all your `Stack`.

And if you want to know if the current touch event is inside each Circle , you could use `GlobalKey`s to get the `RenderBox` for each Circle, then you have the renderBox, and the `PointerEvent`, you can easily check the HitTest, check the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _keyYellow = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _keyRed = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text("title"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Listener(
              onPointerMove: (PointerEvent details) {
                final RenderBox box = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
                final RenderBox boxYellow =
                    _keyYellow.currentContext.findRenderObject();
                final result = BoxHitTestResult();
                Offset localRed = box.globalToLocal(details.position);
                Offset localYellow = boxYellow.globalToLocal(details.position);
                if (box.hitTest(result, position: localRed)) {
                  print("HIT...RED ");
                } else if (boxYellow.hitTest(result, position: localYellow)) {
                  print("HIT...YELLOW ");
                }
              },
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CustomPaint(
                    key: _keyYellow,
                    painter: ShapesPainter(),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 400,
                      width: 400,
                    ),
                  ),
                  CustomPaint(
                    key: _keyRed,
                    painter: ShapesPainter1(),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```